# How index will work on separate date and time column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, indexing

I have two separate columns in Postgres Database for Date and time
I had Index in Date column and time column. As earlier I need to filter the data using date filter only Index worked perfectly. But In recent requirement I need to filter the data using both date and time filter.
when I filter the data by combing date and time like
**concat(date_column, ' ', time_column) ::timestamp>='{var_date_time}'** Date  and time Index does not work . It takes time to fetch the data.

**any way where I can create index by combining both Date and time columns?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index on exactly the expression you are going to use in your WHERE clause. You don't need to cast between a text and a timestamp, just add the two columns:

```
where date_column + time_column >= ...
```

Needs the following index:

```
create index on the_table ( (date_column + time_column) );
```

You might want to think about changing that into a single column in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not a good way to store your data.  It would be better as a single timestamptz column.

With your existing table and index, you can use a tuple comparison:

```
WHERE (date_column,time_column)>(date_constant,time_constant);
```

It is not clear to me if your existing structure is one multi-column index or two single-column indexes.  Either way, it should use (one of) the indexes, but the multi-column would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Is your recent requirement for *date + time* a replacement for the existing or an addition to the existing.  If replacing the current date only requirement then replacing with a single column, as suggested, is the likely the best solution. However, if this is an additional requirement there is an alternative: add a timestamp as as a generated column then create an index on that column:

```
alter table <table> add ts_col timestamp generated always as (date_col+time_col) stored;
create index test_ts_col_ndx on <table> (ts_col);
```

With that your existing queries and dml statements do not change, you only need the new queries where *date+time*  is required. ( see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JJZDZkdu))